# How to resolve - Added Library Loaded - Proposed Google way?

Tags: security, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, libraries

I am getting this message from SCC but am unsure what to tell the dev team on how to resolve it. What is the way that Google has in mind for this?

And is there maybe a way to "whitelist" some libraries and binaries but monitor for others? Because in general, the message makes sense.

In SCC the message is the following:

Added library loaded

```
A library that was not part of the original container image was loaded. If an added library is loaded, this is a possible sign that an attacker has control of the workload and they are executing arbitrary code.
```

Comment: What is the problem? What message from SCC? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi John, sorry for not being clear enough here. I have updated the initial request. I am not sure what the right way to resolve it would be!

Comment: Your question has no details. You will need to analyze the applications and their behavior in the problem container image. The Google documentation for this message is here: https://cloud.google.com/security-command-center/docs/concepts-container-threat-detection-overview

Comment: There are not many details in SCC either. Which is my problem. I mean the application loads libraries once the containers are up and running. Google says in itself that this is an issue. The documentation is not an unknow but does not really help much.

Comment: Unfortunately in your case, your issue requires someone that is very experienced in the behavior of both your application and trojan software. This is the wrong forum for that type of problem. You need professional advice. If you have a security engineer on your team, ask him/her to review your application.